# JQuery parseXML seems to return me nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

First let me shotly clarify what I want to do here:

1. I have a **local XML file** which is **in the same folder as the html page**
2. I want to read that XML file use jQuery and use it's content to fill some divs in the html page (the divs are already there)

So I searched a lot and decided to use the jQuery Ajax GET method to do this. **I also read the offical document .parseXML()** and **try to first learn it by repeating the offical exmaple** (just want to practice a little bit and make sure it works). So the codes I have are these:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        console.log('get the xml successful' + xml);

        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
            $xml = $( xmlDoc );
            $title = $xml.find( "title" );

            console.log('title: ' + $title.text());

            $("#XMLTest").append($title.text());
        }
});
});
```

The XML file named "test.xml" which I used for this try is the same one in the official example but I still want to post it below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version='2.0'>
    <channel>
        <title>RSS Title</title>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

The Problem **seems like that the returned xml data has nothing in it**. **I can see in the browser console the first console.log**. Which is

```
get the xml: links successful[object XMLDocument]
```

So **I suggest that the xml is successfully loaded**. But I got **nothing in my seconde console.log**, it shows just nothing:

```
title:
```

Also **in the div container with the "id = XMLTest" I can't find any child element**.

I assume there must be something very small but I missed, so I would very appreciate if someone can point that out to help me learn some new things.

Comment: see how `xml` is a `[object XMLDocument]` - you don't need to `$.parseXML( xml );` because `xml` is already an xml document

Comment: You have already set the datatype to return as XML so no need to parse it again. Just remove these two lines and try again:         `var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
            $xml = $( xmlDoc );`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments. I now understand the problem and succefully corrected the codes.